# How to configure arduino ide for Python?

Tags: python, arduino

I recently bought arduino uno. I am not much familiar with C# which is used in arduino software. I know that boards like  nodemcu can run on python and it is much easier to code with python. My main language is python. So, I want to know If I can configure the python in arduino IDE.

Comment: A NodeMCU board has 100 times the Flash, 32 times the RAM, and 5 times the clock speed of an Arduino Uno.  Python is simply not an option available to you, no matter what IDE you use.

Comment: Arduino is C++, not C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can use python to code your arduino board.

you can refer this link. https://realpython.com/arduino-python/

Comment: The only Python programming mentioned at that link is running on a PC, *not* the Arduino.